# How to append new data without deleting old ones? (Python,Pandas;BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

What I'm trying to do is that every time this file runs, it appends the new data down without deleting the old ones.

When I run it this way, it completely deletes the old file and rewrites it.

Also, if you have any other ideas where I can improve the code, I'd appreciate it if you could share them.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import time

url = 'https://www.teknosa.com/laptop-notebook-c-116004?s=%3Arelevance%3Aseller%3Ateknosa&page={page}'
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
data=[]
for page in range(1,6):
    req=requests.get(url.format(page=page),headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_='prd')
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

    for job in jobs:
        data.append({
            'Tarih': date.today(),
            'Saat': current_time,
            'Ürün Açıklaması' : job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['title'],
            'Account Kod' : job.find('button', class_='prd-favorite btn-add-favorites')['data-product-id'],
            'Fiyat' : job.find('span', class_='prc prc-last').text.strip(),
            'URL': "https://www.teknosa.com" + job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['href'],
        })

def append_df_to_excel(df, excel_path):
    df_excel = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
    result = pd.concat([df_excel, df], ignore_index=True)
    result.to_excel(excel_path, index=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
append_df_to_excel(df, r"test.xlsx")
```

Edit:Hello again everyone,

I found a code that will partially solve my problem, I wanted to share it with you, but now I am facing another problem.

Every time I run the file, it continues by corrupting the previous time format, as in the example.

[Error Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P974N.png)

I could not understand whether the problem is related to the code or an excel error, I appreciate your help in advance.

Edit 2: I found the solution for myself, in case u need im dropping it here.

```
for pageteknosa in range(1,6):
    reqteknosa=requests.get(urlteknosa.format(page=pageteknosa),headers=headers)
    soupteknosa = BeautifulSoup(reqteknosa.text, 'lxml')
    jobsteknosa = soupteknosa.find_all('div', class_='prd')
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    for jobteknosa in jobsteknosa:
        datateknosa.append({
            'LFR' : "Teknosa",
            'Kategori': "Notebook",
            'Tarih': now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            'Saat': current_time,
            'Ürün Açıklaması' : jobteknosa.find('a', class_='prd-link')['title'],
            'Account Kod' : int(jobteknosa.find('button', class_='prd-favorite btn-add-favorites')['data-product-id']),
            'Fiyat': float(jobteknosa.find('span', class_='prc prc-last').text.replace(" TL",""))*1000,
            'URL': "https://www.teknosa.com" + jobteknosa.find('a', class_='prd-link')['href']
```

}),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will show the actual and the right way of scraping. It will minimize your code and time 5 times.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import time

url = 'https://www.teknosa.com/laptop-notebook-c-116004?s=%3Arelevance%3Aseller%3Ateknosa&page={page}'
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
data=[]
for page in range(1,6):
    req=requests.get(url.format(page=page),headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_='prd')
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

    for job in jobs:
        data.append({
            'Tarih': date.today(),
            'Saat': current_time,
            'xy' : job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['title'],
            'Account Kod' : job.find('button', class_='prd-favorite btn-add-favorites')['data-product-id'],
            'Fiyat' : job.find('span', class_='prc prc-last').text.strip(),
            'URL': "https://www.teknosa.com" + job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['href'],
        })

df=pd.DataFrame(data)#.to_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df)
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the code  rather than authentication. When I open the url :
https://www.teknosa.com/laptop-notebook-c-116004?s=%3Arelevance%3Aseller%3Ateknosa&page=1
It's throwing The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.

Comment: It may not be possible to access the web page from the country you are in. The code you shared worked really well, the problem I had was that when I exported the file to Excel, it changed the date format of the previous saved information.

When I run it for the first time, I do not encounter such a problem, but when I run it on the same file for the second time, the new information comes out in the correct format, while the date information in the old information is corrupted.

Comment: Actually, we can't go beyond the rules: see pandas excel doc:https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel